# why sed is not replacing special character <

Tags: command-line, postfix, sed

I am trying to replace charater < with empty or no charaeter in this file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

My script is

```
sudo sed -i 's/\<\/etc\/dovecot\/private\/dovecot\.pem/\/etc\/dovecot\/private\/dovecot\.pem/g' /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
```

It didn't work then tired:-

```
sudo sed -i '0,/\<\/etc\/dovecot\/private\/dovecot\.pem/s/\<\/etc\/dovecot\/private\/dovecot\.pem/\/etc\/dovecot\/private\/dovecot\.pem/' /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
```

It didn't work as well. What is wrong and how can I do it? Also, it is long. How can I split it multiple lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sed, `\<` matches "beginning of a word", while plain `<` matches literally.

For a more readable substitution, change the delimiters:

```
sed -i 's=</etc/dovecot/private/dovecot\.pem=/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem=g'
```

There's no need to backslash dots in the replacement part.

You can further shorten the instruction by using a capture:

```
sed -i 's=<\(/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot\.pem\)=\1=g'
```

Comment: Wonderful it workes. Perhaps the capture totally new to me. Could you please describe how it works? I am sure ur explanation will help others as well.

Comment: Each part between `\(..\)` is captured. The `\1` refers to the first capture (yes, you can have more than one).

Comment: Strange enough same script works fine in the local Ubuntu. But it is not working in AWS EC2. Same version of Ubuntu running there. Of couser, I am running as with
 sudo

Comment: How do you run the script in AWS?

Comment: I mean, how exactly do you run it? Please post the exact command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93969/discussion-between-masiboo-and-choroba).